# Fantastic Four: Meeting God -- Where's the Challenge After That?

Tags: story-identification, comics, marvel, fantastic-four

A friend was telling me about a storyline in the Fantastic Four where one of them died, so they confronted God and asked to have everything set right.  When I search for this, I keep getting "God War," but that doesn't seem to be the right story arc.

First, what is the name of the story arc where they did meet God (so I can find it), and, second, if they can simply go to God when one of them dies and ask for them to be brought back to life, where is the challenge after that?  Why not just do the same thing every time one of them dies?  This same friend told me that in a recent storyarc, the Human torch died - why can't they just go back to God and ask for his life back again?

It seems to me including an event like this can remove suspense from later stories, so I'd like to read it, but would also be interested in knowing how it was handled so as not to just create a "get out of heaven free" card that can be played whenever necessary.

[image: God is designing Ben]

Comment: It's #3 on Cracked.com's list of absurd ways to resurrect a superhero.
http://www.cracked.com/article_18835_5-absurd-ways-comic-books-have-resurrected-dead-superheroes.html

Comment: I don't understand the picture.

Comment: @JDługosz: the picture is from the story that I was asking about.  Check the answer below, by BenjaminRH for a link to the explanation.

Comment: So you already had the story info in a question asking for that info?

Comment: @JDługosz: Actually, it doesn't matter what info I had before posting a question.  That's moot.  But the info I did have was there was an FF story where they search for God to restore The Thing.  But if you want to know about the picture or the text, you can check the info about the edit indicated above - it will tell you that SS-3 added the photo when editing this post.

Comment: That's confusing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happened in Fantastic Four [#511 "Hereafter"](http://marvel.com/digital_comics/issue/1850/fantastic_four_1997_511) which was released in 2004. You can find the [script here](http://www.dreamland-comics.com/FF511v3.pdf), but to answer your second question, God says that the method they used to contact him couldn't be used again. It's pretty clear that they can't return to God for help in the future.

Comment: They use this so often in the comics, it ought to have its on page on tvtropes: a hero is brought back to life by a method which we are told will never work again (because that would make all future danger meaningless), and which was never mentioned before (because the writers just made it up). I hear this has happened to Superman about a dozen times.

Comment: @Beta Here it is: [It Only Works Once](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ItOnlyWorksOnce) (Warning: TVTropes!)